# Android: Changing visibility of a view in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-viewholder

I have implemented a `recyclerView` in my project.

I have a `Button` in my `recyclerView` `row`. The code for my each row of `recyclerView` is like this:

**savedmessage_custom_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Dummy text" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The visibility of button is `gone`. I want to change the visibility of this button to 'visible' when someone clicks on the `message` `textView` above it. I implemented a simple `onClickLiestener()` on the `message (textView)` and changed the visibility of `button`on click of the `message`. I knew that wasn't going to work but I wanted to see the results. The results are weird. If I click on the textView of row 1, the button of row 7,17,19 etc **also** becomes visible. I can guess this might be coz of caching of the viewHolder.

MyViewHolder is something like this:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView message;
    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me how can I change the visibility of a button, **of a perticular row only**, of my recyclerView?

Comment: Please post your adapter code.  You will need to add a property to model the button's visible state.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the click logic away from the ViewHolder:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView message;
    Button button;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
```

and place it inside the method onBindViewHolder of your adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    holder.message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

ViewHolder is reused by the RecyclerView, that's why you are seeing the button visible in other rows.

Comment: Ah this is as simple as it could be. Thanks. It worked.

Comment: What if i want to hold the clicked view even after scrolling?

Comment: repeat question: i need know hold view after scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is recycling the view so this things are happening.
For that you have to create global variable

```
ArrayList<Boolean> isClicked = new ArrayList<>();
```

and save the value isClicked.

and onBindView holder put something like this:

```
if(isClicked.get(position)){
    view.setvisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
 }else{
    view.setvisiblity(View.GONE);
}
```

and on **OnClickListener** save value in the arraylist as well as set visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage `visibility` of particular `button`, of a particular row in `@Override` method `onBindViewHolder` rather than at initialize time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Remove Visiblity=gone from XML.
Change MyViewHOlder Constructor to;

```
public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    button =(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setVisibility(View.Gone);
    message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Another way;
Still no Visibility=Gone in XML

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   holder.message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener{
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
          holder.button.setVisibiltiy(View.VISIBLE);
       }
   });
   holder.button.setVisibity(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Same results. No success.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the onClick listeners from onBindView() rather than on the View Holder. That's how I always do it.

Comment: Hey thats a nice idea. Let me try. Oops someone downvoted. But I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Great to hear that. Congrats. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score -3):

do like this

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView message;
Button btnShow;
public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    btnShow = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
}

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     btnShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```