# changing visibility of a recyclerview item changes other item's visibility

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with an adapter... the recyclerview has items with a like,unlike buttons. when i click (like) button the (unlike) should become invisibile and vise versa..every thing is working fine but when i click (like) in an item the (unlike) in other items is also becoming invisible as if I am clicking the same button in other views
I already tried this answer but it did not work [Android: Changing visibility of a view in recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363068/android-changing-visibility-of-a-view-in-recyclerview)
here is the adapter code :

```
    package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.opengl.Visibility
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.*
import android.widget.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.itemm.view.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileReader

/**
 * Created by Ahmed on 10/14/2018.
 */

class ItemmAdapter(private val mItems: Array<File>,private val activity:Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemmAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var parent:ViewGroup

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.itemm, parent, false)
        this.parent=parent
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = mItems[position]
        holder.itemView.layoutParams=RecyclerView.LayoutParams(parent.context.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels/2,RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)



        //holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image).setImageResource(R.drawable.icons8_cycling_104)
        //holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.description).text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzضصثقفغعهخحجدطكمنتالبيسشذئءؤرلاىة"
        //holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price).text="10000$"
        holder.like.setOnClickListener{
            holder.like.visibility=View.GONE
            holder.unlike.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
        holder.unlike.setOnClickListener{
            holder.unlike.visibility=View.GONE
            holder.like.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
        holder.shopping.setOnClickListener{
            holder.shopping.visibility=View.GONE
            holder.notshopping.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
        holder.notshopping.setOnClickListener{
            holder.notshopping.visibility=View.GONE
            holder.shopping.visibility=View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mItems.size
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val like=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.like)
        val unlike=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.unlike)
        val shopping=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.shopping)
        val notshopping=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.notShopping)


    }

}
```

help me please

Comment: What about when you click on shopping and not shopping?

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass also the same problem occures when clicking shopping/notshopping

Comment: no i do not think so@Dr4ketheb4dass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because its a recycler view (so the view gets recycled as you scroll and the visibility of the like or unlike sticks there.

Modify your item object to include a boolean `isLiked` and set that to true or false on the onClick:

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener{
            item.setIsLiked(true);
        }

holder.unlike.setOnClickListener{
            item.setIsLiked(false);
        }
```

and set the view visibility based on that:

```
holder.like.visibility=item.getIsLiked() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE; 
holder.unlike.visibility=item.getIsLiked() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
```

**note**: setIsLiked(boolean like) and getIsLiked() could be different names if you use auto-generated getters and setters;

do same for shopping notshopping

Comment: Use proper Kotlin way of setting and getting (I don't think .set and .get is the right way, I guess you should do .isLiked=true and .isLiked)

Answer (score 1):

only **use bind for setting item content** in every item and **move listeners from bind method to holder class**:

```
inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var liked = false
        var shopped = false
        val like=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.like)
        val unlike=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.unlike)
        val shopping=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.shopping)
        val notshopping=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.notShopping)

        init{

           like?.setOnClickListener{
                 liked = true
                 like.visibility=View.GONE
                 unlike.visibility=View.VISIBLE
           }
           unlike?.setOnClickListener{
                  liked = false
                  unlike.visibility=View.GONE
                  like.visibility=View.VISIBLE
           }
           shopping?.setOnClickListener{
                  shopped = true 
                  shopping.visibility=View.GONE
                  notshopping.visibility=View.VISIBLE
           }
           notshopping?.setOnClickListener{
                  shopped = false
                  notshopping.visibility=View.GONE
                  shopping.visibility=View.VISIBLE
           }
       }

       fun bind(){// call this from onBind method of adapter
         if(liked) like?.performClick() else unlike?.performClick()
         if(shopped) shopping?.performClick() else notshopping?.performClick()
       }

    }
```