# Changing visibility of button in viewholder of recyclerview (cardview is used)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, cardview

This question is already answered but not for cardview I guess, I have already gone through most answers and experimented with them still my problem is not solved.

I have a recyclerview with adapter and a cardview now I have added a button in a cardview and I want to change the visibility of this button to invisible when the button is clicked, but when I do so the visibility of other buttons in other cards like at position=9 get affected and becomes invisible but I never clicked the button at 9th card.

I found some solutions like writing the onClick under onBindViewHolder method. I did so but still its not working please help!

Here is the code for cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/shop_cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="280dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/btnGrey">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/shopVolleyImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/pyaa_logo_iii"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shopImageNameTV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Json Image Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the code for recyclerviewadapter

```
    public class shopRecyclerViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<shopRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<shopDataAdapter> dataAdapters;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public shopRecyclerViewAdapter(List<shopDataAdapter> getDataAdapter,Context context){
        super();
        this.dataAdapters=getDataAdapter;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_shop,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, int position) {
        shopDataAdapter dataAdapterOBJ= dataAdapters.get(position);
        imageLoader=shopImageAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(dataAdapterOBJ.getshopImageUrl(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                        Viewholder.VollyImageView,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert
                )
        );
        Viewholder.VollyImageView.setImageUrl(dataAdapterOBJ.getshopImageUrl(),imageLoader);
        Viewholder.ImageTitleTV.setText(dataAdapterOBJ.getshopName());
        Viewholder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Viewholder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView ImageTitleTV;
        public NetworkImageView VollyImageView;
        public Button check;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ImageTitleTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopImageNameTV);
            VollyImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopVolleyImageView);
            check=itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at similar question, like this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363068/android-changing-visibility-of-a-view-in-recyclerview ?

Comment: yes, thats the first one I referred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this declare global variable clickPosition = -1

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {
    Viewholder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Viewholder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickPosition = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    if(clickPosition == position){
        Viewholder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Don't forgot to write line Viewholder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); otherwise it will give strange behavior.

If you can give more explain what particular behavior you want I can give more explanation or exact solution.